# Module "x" has no exported member

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, node-modules

am learning angular and i try to make a scheduler app.
i found a perfect module for that here :

> https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Scheduler/Overview/Angular/Light/

i've created the calendrierComponent and here's what i've done :

**calendrier.component.css**

```
/deep/ .options {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/deep/ .caption {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
/deep/ .option {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
}
/deep/ .switcher-mode {
    width: 100%;
}
/deep/ .option > span {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
/deep/ .option > .dx-selectbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**calendrier.component.html**

```
<dx-scheduler
    style="height: 1000px; width: 1500px; display: block"
    [dataSource]="appointments"
    [currentDate]="currentDate"
    startDateExpr="StartDate"
    endDateExpr="EndDate"
    textExpr="Text"
    [views]="['agenda','month','workWeek']"
    currentView="week"
    [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
    [startDayHour]="8"
    [endDayHour]="19"
    [resources]="resources"
></dx-scheduler>
```

**calendrier.component.ts**

```
import {NgModule, Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {Appointment, Resource, Service} from './calendrier.service';
import {DxSchedulerModule, DxCheckBoxModule, DxSelectBoxModule} from 'devextreme-angular';

if(!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
    enableProdMode();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'calendrier',
    templateUrl: 'calendrier/calendrier.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['calendrier/calendrier.component.css'],
    providers: [Service]
})
export class calendrierComponent {
    appointmentsData: Appointment[];
    currentDate: Date = new Date(2015, 4, 25);
    resourcesData: Resource[];
    switchModeNames: string[];

    constructor(service: Service) {
        this.switchModeNames = ["Tabs", "Drop-Down Menu"];

        this.appointmentsData = service.getAppointments();
        this.resourcesData = service.getResources();
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DxSchedulerModule,
        DxCheckBoxModule,
        DxSelectBoxModule
    ],
    declarations: [calendrierComponent],
    bootstrap: [calendrierComponent]
})
export class calendrierModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(calendrierModule)
```

**calendrier.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

export class Appointment {
    text: string;
    ownerId: number[];
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}

export class Resource {
    text: string;
    id: number;
    color: string;
}

let appointments: Appointment[] = [
    {
        text: "Website Re-Design Plan",
        ownerId: [4],
        startDate: new Date(2015, 4, 25, 9, 30),
        endDate: new Date(2015, 4, 25, 11, 30)
    }, {
        text: "Stand-up meeting",
        ownerId: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        startDate: new Date(2015, 4, 25, 9, 0),
        endDate: new Date(2015, 4, 25, 9, 15),
    }
];

let resources: Resource[] = [
    {
        text: "Samantha Bright",
        id: 1,
        color: "#cb6bb2"
    }, {
        text: "John Heart",
        id: 2,
        color: "#56ca85"
    }, {
        text: "Todd Hoffman",
        id: 3,
        color: "#1e90ff"
    }, {
        text: "Sandra Johnson",
        id: 4,
        color: "#ff9747"
    }
];

@Injectable()
export class Service {
    getAppointments(): Appointment[] {
        return appointments;
    }
    getResources(): Resource[] {
        return resources;
    }
}
```

here is also my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "CroissantBoard",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "GFY",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "www.lol.com"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached  --port 3001 --hot",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "devextreme": "^17.1.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^17.1.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "primeng": "^4.1.0-rc.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devextreme": "~17.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/dot": "^1.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "ts2.0",
    "@types/mkdirp": "^0.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.51",
    "@types/yargs": "^6.3.2",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "dot": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.8",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-merge-json": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "gulp-tslint": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "http-server": "0.8.5",
    "inflector-js": "^1.0.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.2",
    "jasmine": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "0.5.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

and my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors":true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "app/**/*.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

So here's my question : how can i resolve these errors :

```
Error   Typescript  Module '"/home/moonshine/desktop/test Schedule/angular2-website-routes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.    1:9
Error   Typescript  Module '"/home/moonshine/desktop/test Schedule/angular2-website-routes/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'BrowserModule'.   2:9
Error   Typescript  Module '"/home/moonshine/desktop/test Schedule/angular2-website-routes/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"' has no exported member 'platformBrowserDynamic'.
```

Comment: Link does not open. But by the way, out of curiousity, did you install all the node packages using the command `npm install` in that project folder?. This error generally occurs when you have not installed the packages for your project folder.

Comment: thanks for answering, i already did that and here's what i've got on my console :
 `npm WARN devextreme-angular@17.1.4 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.2.1 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN CroissantBoard@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
npm WARN The package devextreme is included as both a dev and production dependency.
`

Comment: 1. remove `devextreme` from devDependencies or dependencies depending on whether it is required for production. 2. run the command `npm install --save @angular/forms@^4.0.0` 3. I cannot find the CroissantBoard package in npm. So may be skip that and then try working. Its a outdated code so possibly will not work as well.

Comment: thanks for helping but the errors still persist :(

Comment: Could you create a plunkr?

Comment: here it is ( it's the first time i use plunkr so sorry if it's incomplete ) :
https://plnkr.co/edit/zgAiLN9jpDUSzFiC3ScY?p=info

Comment: Not much help. Dont understand the `import {DxSchedulerModule, DxCheckBoxModule, DxSelectBoxModule} from 'devextreme-angular';`

Comment: it's the requirement for the devextreme's schedule plugin

Comment: Ok. Can you put a plunker like this. May be you can fork it and make changes. But do get me the actual code. Else it becomes difficult to troubleshoot.  https://plnkr.co/edit/acLvnOvezEFI4EXjKbVx?p=preview

Comment: here it is if it can help you : https://plnkr.co/edit/wwM8taaL9zcoi0qNQXh8?p=preview